# DIV com height:auto; não se reajusta de acordo com a altura da DIV interna

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma DIV com **height:auto;** que não ajusta a altura de acordo com uma div interna com **height:120px;**

**Veja o CSS**

```
.conteudo-modelo-3-0 {
width:960px;
height:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.conteudo-modelo-3-1{    
position:relative;
width:840px;
height:120px;
float:right;
background-color:#666666;
}
```

A DIV **conteudo-modelo-3-0** não se reajusta de acordo com a altura de **conteudo-modelo-3-1**.

O que faço para corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em resumo, isso acontece porque a div interna (child) está utilizando o atributo **float**. Quando se utiliza o atributo float, o elemento fica "flutuando" e por isso a div pai (parent), não consegue identificar a altura do filho (child). OK, como resolver? A resposta está em utilizar o **clear: both;**.

A maneira mais utilizada hoje é através do pseudo elemento **after**. Cria-se uma classe geral chamada **clearfix**, com os seguintes atributos:

```
.clearfix:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Então respondendo a sua pergunta, ficaria assim:

```
<div class="conteudo-modelo-3-0 clearfix">
  <div class="conteudo-modelo-3-1"></div>
</div>
```

Criei um fiddle para dar um exemplo: [Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/7kyy7z1z/3/)

Créditos: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar um ```overflow: auto```? ```.clearfix``` é muito _overrated_ mas da pra resolver a maior parte só com o overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a propriedade `overflow: auto`.

Ficará assim.

```css
.conteudo-modelo-3-0 {
  width:960px;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.conteudo-modelo-3-1 {    
  position:relative;
  width:840px;
  height:120px;
  float:right;
  background-color:#666666;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo-modelo-3-0">
  <div class="conteudo-modelo-3-1"></div>
</div>
```

> O `overflow: auto` irá servir apenas quando o `height` não estiver com uma altura definida.